# Node: Connect angular 6 client to Node server

Tags: node.js, angular

I have node TCP socket server that i implemented using `net` module as shown in below

```
const net = require("net");
const server = net.createServer();
server.on("connection", function (socket) {
    socket.setEncoding('utf8');
      socket.on("data", function (d) {
      }
}
socket.on("end", function () {
        clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket), 1);
        console.log('end event on socket fired');
    });
```

and i want my angular 6 app as a client to this TCP server. So i explore on the internet i only get with socket.io. Basic scenario is i have two clients one is raspberry which communicate on TCP/IP to my server and one is angular app that communicate with server using http. Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of my knowledge plain TCP/UDP connections from the browser is currently deprecated because of security issues. I believe you may have to use WebSockets both on angular and node sides.

Comment: Thanks for responding Janith but i have one client like raspberry which only connect with TCP to server so that i desigh this TCP server and end client is browser which is not responding on TCP

Comment: Websockets is also a TCP connection, As of my knowledge I don't see why rapsberry pi cannot connect with TCP. Even though you can always implement to protocols on the server side one for Plain TCP and one for WS.

Comment: hello Janith i connect angular application to TCP server now my TCP server handles both client Raspberry pi and browser too, Thanks for your time

Comment: Hii Pradip so did you able to connect your server via TCP?? or websockets?

Comment: I made combination of TCP and web socket to build my server which can handle both type of request